# Custom Arc Drawable ProgressBar

Tags: customview, android, java

Необходимо сделать плавно заполняющийся `ProgressBar` следующего вида:
[image]

Есть ресурсы
`background.png`

[image]

`progress.png`

[image]

Пробовал делать так
`main.xml`

```
<ProgressBar
  android:id="@+id/progressBar"
  style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
  android:layout_width="250dp"
  android:layout_height="100dp"
  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
  android:background="@drawable/background"
  android:max="100"
  android:progressDrawable="@drawable/back_arc" >
</ProgressBar>
```

`back_arc.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <item android:id="@+id/bar_value">
      <clip
         android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
         android:drawable="@drawable/progress" />
   </item>
</layer-list>
```

Результат получился немного не такой.
[image]

Comment: интересно, так оно у тебя заработало? ты переопределял адаптер для прогресс бара или пробовал менять скин?

Comment: `Thread` c отправкой `handler` и в нем `incrementProgressBy()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C помощью стандартного `ProgressBar` заявленную штуку не получилось сделать. Результат был достигнут с помощью `RelativeLayout` и наложением картинок друг на друга - снизу progress.png затем фон, который с помощью `Rotate` двигался в виде "заслонки" и поверх фон с дыркой под дугу (расписал, может кому-нибудь и пригодится).